# HttpCore - saving entity as a blob

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm new to server programming and httpcore, and I'm trying to save entities from incoming HttpResponse to a database as blob (assume I must use blob and can't use some other type)

I found that I can serialize objects and them send them as bytearray, but I when I try to serialize an entity I get an exception.

code:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)){
        oos.writeObject(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("error serializing entity");
        return false;
    }
    byte[] entityAsBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(entityAsBytes);
```

the line that fails is

```
oos.writeObject(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer. there is a build in function for serialization of entity to byte array. all that is needed is this line:

```
EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
```